# How to concatenate two fields from contacts and store it in a field in account object

Tags: account, contact

I have a field called **`Concate__c`** in account object. I need to get the two fields value (**`Car__c`** and **`Bike__c`**) and display it in the field. Through coding i can done. But i am checking for some alternative solution to do it through configuration. I tried workflow, formula field but i was not able to include any contact fields in the account object.

Please provide me a solution !! or coding is the only possible way ?

Comment: The thing is an account can have multiple contacts.How would you determine which record's fields you want to grab??

Comment: actually to be more precise my question is , contacts have 3 record types. A , B ,C .. If contacts created through B rec type having Bike__c value as "yamaha" for 1 record and "suzuki" for another record. I want to display "yamaha,suzuki, in concate field

Comment: Still the same question i asked in previous comment persist.Try to frame question properly.To get you started, is there any field on account which is a lookup of contact whose field values you want to populate on account's field??